# Trouble setting up and debugging PHP Storm project from existing files in mounted / shared folder

Tags: php, linux, xdebug, remote-debugging, phpstorm

I am struggling to debug a PHPstorm project from a remote server. I want to debug a specific file called index.php. I right click and press debug but it pops up with the configuration box  with a list of fields and a error at the bottom telling me that the PHP interpreter isnt installed and click to fix your project. But on the PHP window to select a interpreter it only has a drop down of local files and folders? this is incorrect as the whole point of this is PHP, Xdebug etc is on a remote server and I want to debug using that remote server. Its like it expects that I have installed a local server and wants me to select the folder in my host machine.

The details so far

**Host Machine:** Windows 7
**Guest Machine:** Debian virtual machine (Virtual Box)

Guest details from phpinfo

**SERVER ADDR** 192.168.0.7
**SERVER NAME** 192.168.0.7
**REMOTE ADDR** 192.168.0.4

Xdebug is installed along on the guest machine

xdebug entry in PHP,INI file

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host= 192.168.56.1
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
```

Host details of windows machine from ipconfig

**Connection-specific DNS Suffix**  . :
 **Link-local IPv6 Address** . . . . . : fe80::409c:7bf8:5989:cb02%24
 **IPv4 Address**. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
 **Subnet Mask** . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 **Default Gateway** . . . . . . . . . :

What I have setup on PHP Storm

1. I have set up the deployment correctly by using a mounted shared folder. Files are syncing from local project folder to shared folder and thus to the remote files on the remote server
2. I have setup a Server on the PHP / Servers tab, the details are **Host** (http bit it wont let me put a link in)192.168.0.7, **Port** 80, **Debugger** Xdebug. The path mappings are mapped to the project path on the remote server to the project path on the local files.

There is no PHP deployment environment set-up on the PHP storm settings and no PHP IDE key registration with Xdebug. I couldn't access the help page on PHP storm website. I validated the remote host and it has the Information symbol next to the following messeges

- PHP.ini file
- Xdebug with its version number 2.2.1
- Remote host 192.168.56.1

So thats my problem, sorry for the massive explaination but I really need to solve this. If you need more detail please let me know and I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: Where is your Apache server installed??

Comment: The Apache server is installed on the Debian guest machine (remote server)

Comment: So on your Debian Machine you have the Apache Server+Php+XDebug, and on that machine you have served your PhpStorm project, right??

Comment: On that remote machine there is a folder www which is shared on the windows machine as folder called test.

Comment: So your dev environment is on the Windows Machine, right?

Comment: The dev enviroment is on the Linux remote machine. Everything from Apache to Xdebug, Mysql and the project files. The php storm project files are local on the windows machine but are in sync with the files on the linux machine.

Comment: This is the first time i see such dev configuration...so then, you are using the Windows Machine like some sort of repo, right?

Comment: **1)** PHP Interpreters are used for **local** script execution and debugging and you do not need them if everything is executed on remote machine (be it real computer or VM). **2)** Double check your IP (where PhpStorm is running). It must match the **IP as seen from remote** (it easily could be `192.168.0.4` instead of `192.168.56.1` based on your info). Alternatively -- try `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` so it always connects back to calling machine (can be insecure if your server is accessed by many people).

Comment: **3)** Make sure that xdebug port is enabled in firewall (as well as in router, if you have one between your PC and server -- use port forwarding for that). **4)** Do a simple test: activate "phone-handle" icon so PhpStorm will start listening for incoming xdebug connections (in case you did not know -- it's xdebug who connects to IDE). Verify that correct port is opened (using `netstat` or another similar tool). Now, using `telnet` on your server -- connect to your IP and xdebug port. If unable -- then you are doing something wrong / still missing something.

Comment: **5)** Instead of setting up `PHP | Servers` manually (in case you are doing it first time or not sure on details), better delete it and follow Zero-Config debug approach -- IDE will help you with setting it up of all fields (except mapping, maybe) -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: At the moment I think it could be either wrong IP (VM uses NAT, right? So `192.168.0.4` could be the actual correct IP) or firewall (actually, on VM side -- being the case in few threads lie yours).

Comment: ... and **6)** -- use xdebug logging feature -- it can help solving problems MUCH faster: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: I am using Bridged Adaptor. I have changed the remote host on the xdebug settings so its now 192.168.0.4. I made a log path and I clicked on the listen for debugger button. Nothing happens and a log isnt even generated in the directory I have specified it. I am not very famililar with netstat and ports and firewalls.

Comment: Just clicking "listen for" button is not enough -- you need to make request to the debugged page/url (the zero config manual has it all). If not -- http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ . P.S. Do not forget to restart Apache after making changes in php.ini (required depends on how you run php under Apache).

Comment: Do whatever needs to be done until you get entries in xdebug log file (for example: configure xdebug to attempt to debug every single request: `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` .. or place `xdebug_break();` line in your code to programatically trigger breakpoint).

Comment: Thanks for your help @LazyOne I will have to try your advice out and see if I can get it working after Christmas.